# Tabs in .NET TabControl/TabPage are Ugly

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I am creating tabs in C#'s TabControl, and while that is very easy to do, they are extremely ugly.  I did some searching around the internet and [found a company that sells graphical improvements to various GUI components](http://www.dotnetmagic.com/) in .NET, but that costs $400.  Given that I am working on a master's project, that is out of the question, does anybody have any other suggestions for "prettying" up the tabs.  Thanks.

**Edit**: My mistake - I forgot to put that I am using Windows.Forms.

Comment: Windows Forms? WPF? Which TabControl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The* place to look for free code for .NET is [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com).

A quick search there found this nice looking tab control (in WinForms):
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/KRBTabControl.aspx

No need for WPF quite yet...

Comment: I like this, and seems like it would work.  Only problem - I can't seem to bring it into my solution.  Even if I bring the entire project in, it complains (loudly).  If I can get it working, I'll mark your answer (for now, +1).

Comment: Nice find, and it seems like the licence allows any kind of use.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going the free route, try the following:

- Add more padding to the tab headers (TabControl.Padding) The default of 6,3 makes the headers look crowded.
- Use icons.  Populate the image list (TabControl.ImageList) and pull the images out per tab page via TabPage.ImageIndex or TabPabe.ImageKey.

The WPF suggestion above is also valid -- it's free and you can make it look nice fairly easily .  The downside is there is some ramp-up if you're not familiar with the technology.

Answer (score 1):

Can we assume you are using Windows Forms at this point?  I suggest maybe looking into WPF instead.  [The WPF toolkit on codeplex has a very nice Ribbon Control](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx) which might be a good substitute for the standard tab control.

Answer (score 1):

my tabs look fine, what's your beef?

post a picture or your 'ugly' tabs, and post a picture of what you think 'pretty' tabs should look like; owner-drawn controls can do a lot...

but if this is for your thesis, unless your thesis is on graphical design, "pretty" tabs are probably a waste of time!

Comment: Not for a master's thesis, just a project in a master's class.  I finished the "hard" work early and I wanted to pretty up the interface and took this as a learning experience (which, given that I didn't know much about WPF, it looks like it's going to be).